# Комбинировать запрос на создание таблицы и триггера. FireBird 2.5

Tags: firebird

Имеется запрос на создание таблицы если такой таблицы еще нет.
Запрос выполняется из PHP.

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MY_TABLE')) THEN
    EXECUTE STATEMENT '
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)';
END
```

Можно ли в этом же блоке, выполнить еще запрос на создание триггера (и если да то как это правильно написать в одном общем запросе)?

Запрос создания триггера.

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER MY_TABLE_TRIGGER_NAME FOR MY_TABLE ACTIVE
BEFORE INSERT POSITION 1
AS 
BEGIN 
    if (new.id is null ) then
    new.id = gen_id (generator_name, 1);
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Надо ли опускать команды `SET TERM ^ ;` и `SET TERM ; ^` в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно, и нужно, подробнее ниже.

Нет, команды `SET TERM` в данном случае не нужны. Это вообще команды не Firebird, а клиентской программы (я полагаю вы используете IBExpert). Большой текст запроса разделяется на отдельные куски между терминаторами и каждый кусок отправляется на сервер отдельным запросом. `SET TERM` меняет текущий символ терминатора на другой. IBExpert выставляет `SET TERM ^;` перед любым автоматически сгенерированным PSQL-блоком, потому что внутри могут использоваться символы `;`

В вашем случае для разделения стоит использовать отдельные `EXECUTE STATEMENT`

Примерно так:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MY_TABLE')) THEN
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'CREATE TABLE ...';
    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'CREATE TRIGGER ...';
  END
END
```